# Preamble code to automatically delete some commands in .tex file

Tags: preamble

I would be very grateful for help to resolve a bug. I need to use a preamble specification to automatically delete two commands in a tex file which result from a conflict between different document classes. The commands are:

```
\author{\phantom{0}}

\affiliation{\phantom{0}}
```

Further background on the bug, including the complete tex file, is available [here](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/342#issuecomment-882474297). I would also be happy to provide any further information as requested.

Thank you very much

Comment: In general LaTeX can't alter the code it sees or delete code in your document. In this case it *appears* that it might be enough to *ignore* the two commands, in which case `\renewcommand\author[1]{}` and `\renewcommand\affiliation[1]{}` before the two offending lines might be enough.

Comment: can't you simply use `\author{your name}` or `\author{}` for no author to replace the dummy initial phantom values. Why do you think there is a bug here?

Comment: I looked at your github. The commands are not "produced by a document class" they are simply in your preamble. So since you anyway need to change the preamble, not using those commands is the most direct solution. If you have no write access to the preamble how can you add any "fix" at all?

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'm going to try your suggestions and report back. Indeed, David, the issue is a conflict between two classes, namely, the APA 6 that comes with the R package and the APA 7 that's been added later.

Comment: P.S. The option I have is to add parameters to the preamble through the R package.

Comment: @moewe's suggestion worked out! Thank you! I added both commands to the preamble through the parameter `header-includes` parameter enabled by the papaja package in R. 

```
header-includes   : 
  - \renewcommand\author[1]{}
  - \renewcommand\affiliation[1]{}
  - \authorsnames[1, 2, 1]{first author, second author, third author}
  - \authorsaffiliations{{first affiliation}, {second affiliation}}
```

The `renewcommand` functions were crucial to override preexisting preambles. David's suggestions didn't work as they required direct editing of those preambles.

Thank you both very much

Comment: @moewe, I've just added the answer for convenience, but if you'd like to add it yourself, that might be fairer. I would then accept your answer (as soon as I get the option from the system).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** The solution below stopped working for me. A new solution is available at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70658799/7050882

---

Solution provided by @moewe in a comment above. Big thanks to @moewe and @DavidCarlisle for superb help.

I added `\renewcommand\author[1]{}` and `\renewcommand\affiliation[1]{}` to the preamble through the `header-includes` parameter of the papaja R package.

```
header-includes: 
  - \renewcommand\author[1]{}
  - \renewcommand\affiliation[1]{}
  - \authorsnames[1, 2, 1]{first author, second author, third author}
  - \authorsaffiliations{{first affiliation}, {second affiliation}}
```

The `renewcommand` function was crucial to override preexisting parameters that I could not directly edit.

Thank you!